# How to access the value parameter of a new object created using JustGage?

Tags: javascript, graphael, justgage

I didn't go digging, because I don't think it matters what methods and so forth JustGage has, but I have this new object `g`.

```
var g = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge", 
    value: 34, 
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
});
```

My question is how do I retrieve the value parameter later in the script.

I thought that `var value = g.value` would work, but it doesn't.

Here is a bit of the justgage.js file:

```
 JustGage = function(config) {

  if (!config.id) {alert("Missing id parameter for gauge!"); return false;}
  if (!document.getElementById(config.id)) {alert("No element with id: \""+config.id+"\" found!"); return false;}

  var obj = this;

  // configurable parameters
  obj.config =
  {
    // id : string
    // this is container element id
    id : config.id,

    // title : string
    // gauge title
    title : (config.title) ? config.title : "",

    // titleFontColor : string
    // color of gauge title
    titleFontColor : (config.titleFontColor) ? config.titleFontColor : "#999999",

    // value : int
    // value gauge is showing
    value : (config.value) ? config.value : 0,
```

Comment: How is `JustGage` defined?

Comment: Elementary, Sherlock! Just provide us what is `JustGage` :)

Comment: It is a very big file, you can look at www.justgage.com if you like.

Comment: It depends on what JustGage does with the object passed to it. If it just throws it away or does not store it in an accessible property on the instance, you can't get it.

Comment: Well there you go. `g.config.value`.

Comment: Here is a link to the source (the .com doesn't have a good source link): https://github.com/toorshia/justgage/blob/master/justgage.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `g.config.value` - from looking at the JustGage source code I think it'll be there.

Comment: I think it is in config also.